# Javascript - Two same functions but just one works only

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have `updateLocation` function with the purpose is to select whether the value is already exist inside the array or not. If it doesn't exist, this function will input the value into the `array` then put it on `state`, and vice versa.

But when I try to click it, I got an error like this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Here's the code I write:

```
updateLocation(e) {
    let locationArray = this.state.checked.location;
    let value         = parseInt(e.target.value);
    //v this is the error comes from v
    if (locationArray.includes(value)) {
      locationArray.splice(locationArray.indexOf(value), 1);
    } else {
      locationArray.push(value)
    }
    this.setState({
      checked: {
        location: locationArray
      }
    })
}
```

I think this error really doesn't make sense because previously there was a function that was almost the same but it works normally.

```
updateCategory(e) {
    let categoryArray = this.state.checked.categories;
    let value         = parseInt(e.target.value);
    //this one works fine even It looks the same like updateLocation()
    if (categoryArray.includes(value)) {
      categoryArray.splice(categoryArray.indexOf(value), 1);
    } else {
      categoryArray.push(value)
    }
    this.setState({
      checked: {
        categories: categoryArray
      }
    })
  }
```

The state

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      jobs    : [],
      category: [],
      location: [],
      loading : true,
      count   : 8,
      checked : {
        categories: [],
        location  : []
      }
    }
  }
```

the `updateCategory` function is located above the update `updateLocation`

This is the code where `updateLocation` is called

```
<div className="card-body">
    {state.location.map((item, i) => (
        <div className="checkbox" key={i}>
           <input type="checkbox" value={item.id} onChange={e => this.updateLocation(e)} checked={state.checked.categories.includes(item.id)}/> {item.city_name}
        </div>
    )}
    <a onClick={e => this.viewAllLocation(e)} id="view-all-loc">View more >>></a>
    <div id="show-loading-loc" style={{display: 'none'}}>Loading...</div>
</div>
```

#### Update:

I tried to `console.log(locationArray.includes(value))` but weirdly there's no error appeared, just the result of the `locationArray.includes(value)` in console which is `false`

#### More update:

I found the main problem, everything in `updateLocation` function works fine but it gets the error when the `locationArray` will be stored in `state`. But it still not makes sense because we already have `checked.location` in state

Comment: are you sure that your locationArray has a value? Based on the error, it seems that your locationArray is undefined, that's why includes method does not work.

Comment: surely this.state.checked does not have location array; console log the same.

Comment: I already update the code. It has a empty array both in `state.checked.location` and `state.checked.categories`

Comment: check  if (locationArray && locationArray.includes(value)){//your code here}

Comment: Can you also post the code where updateLocation function is called?

Comment: @AtinSingh I already update it

Comment: @JeyamPrakash alredy tried before but same error

Comment: What value you get for console.log(locationArray) ?

Comment: Can you also add code where you are calling `updateCategory`?

Comment: can you show the `console.log(locationArray)` above the `if statement` line in `updateLocation` function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem it's that you're assigning to your `checked` object a new instance without the other property.

```
this.setState({
  checked: {
    categories: categoryArray
  }
})
```

This `setState` is deleting the `location` property from `this.state.checked`.

You should use:

```
this.setState({
  checked: {
     ...this.state.checked,
     categories: categoryArray
  }
})
```

Comment: actually, I should put `...this.state.checked` in both of the function and it works now

Comment: @MirukuSheki I think you're mutating directly the `state`. You should `clone()` or `cloneDeep()` these `state` before `push()` or `splice()` them.

Comment: Another way,  to avoid spread syntax, is `this.setState({checked: Object.assign(this.state.checked, {categories: categoryArray})});` to get compatibility with old navigators

Comment: And yes, like @TamDc says, you're mutating you're component state. Aditionally to clone, you can use: `let categoryArray = this.state.checked.categories.splice()`